# Generating a n(rows) by m(columns) chessboard dynamically

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

Imagine the following scenario (Silverlight 4). I have two Rectangles. One is black and one is white. They both have fixed size, say 50x50. I also have an area (500x500) which I want to fill with those rectangles but in an alternating way - white, black, white, black etc. To illustrate better, take a look at the links bellow:

http://screencast.com/t/BwsPSbtg2eaM

http://screencast.com/t/gTuexSSyW

The video (link #2) demonstrates exactly what I am trying to achieve.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Jones

Answer (score 1):

```
    int totalRectsInaRow = TotalWidth/ WidthOfOneRect;
    int totalRectsInaColumn = TotalHeight/ HeightOfOneRect;

    //Create a Grid of Width = TotalWidth and Height = Total Height;
    //Add columns equal to totalRectsInaColumn and rows equal to totalRectsInaRow in Grid
    //Set wdith of each column equal to width of one rectangle
    //set height of each row equal to height of one rectangle

    bool drawWhite = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < totalRectsInaColumn; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < totalRectsInaRow; j++)
        {
            if (drawWhite)
            { 
                //draw white rectanlge at i column and j row
                //basically you create a rectangle and place it in grid on particular location
                DrawWhileRectangle(i, j);
                drawWhite = false;
            }
            else
            {
                //draw black rectanlge at i column and j row
                //basically you create a rectangle and place it in grid on particular location
                DrawBlackRectangle(i, j);
                drawWhite = true;
            }
        }
        drawWhite = !drawWhite;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks...I'm looking for a more XAML approach.